# Begging the question in a proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I've found in my math textbook a proof of De Morgan's law but I think it's begging the question. Here's the proof:
$$ \begin{aligned} x\in(A\cap B)^c&\iff x\notin A\cap B \\
&\iff x\notin A \text{ or } x\notin B \\
&\iff x\in A^c \text{ or } x\in B^c \\
&\iff x\in A^c\cup B^c
\end{aligned}$$
Thus: $(A\cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$ Am I right? If not, why?

Comment: Not sure what exactly is your question. Are you asking whether the proof in your math textbook is correct? What makes you think that it is *not* correct?

Comment: No, it is not begging the question (it is not assuming what you are trying to prove). The $\Rightarrow$ path shows that $(A\cap B)^c$ is contained in $A^c\cup B^c$, and the $\Leftarrow$ path shows that $A^c\cup B^c$ is contained in $(A\cap B)^c$, thus proving equality.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop I think it's incorrect because it's assuming what it has to be proved. How can he pass from  x∉A∩B  to x∉A or x∉B without De Morgan's law.

Comment: How can he turn the "and" in the first into "or"

Comment: @tahafen: It is using the logical version, not the set-theoretic one.

Comment: True: in proving DeMorgan's laws for sets, they use ... DeMorgan's laws in logic. ($\lnot(p\land q)\Leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$). These can be proven (e.g. truth tables - a finite problem altogether).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given proof hides an application of De Morgan's law for propositional logic. Let me write it out in full, expanding "$x \not\in X$" to "$\text{not } x \in X$":

$$ \begin{align*}
 x\in(A\cap B)^c&\iff \text{not} (x\in A\cap B )\\
&\iff \text{not} (x\in A \text{ and } x\in B) \\
&\iff (\text{not } x\in A) \text{ or } (\text{not } x\in B) \tag*{$(*)$}\\
&\iff x\in A^c \text{ or } x\in B^c \\
&\iff x\in A^c\cup B^c
\end{align*}$$

You can use truth tables to check the rule used in step $(*)$.